# Как сделать такую разметку с разным количеством слов в строке?

Tags: java, android, listview, ui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы слова из массива выводились в таком виде: то есть, чтобы на строчку влезало разное количество слов, а остальные переносились, если не влезают?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это вполне может быть обычный `TextView`, а теги - `html`-код, сконвертированный в `Spannable` [`Html.fromHtml(..)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#fromHtml(java.lang.String,%20int)) или текст, обработанный спанами программно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно взять FlexboxLayoutManager + RecyclerView.

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout